# can't figure out how to return the selected row of grid in ModalDialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I've been looking and cant find the answer.  I have a ASPxGrid on a modalDialog.  When the dialog closes i want to return the data (and if possible the fields behind the columns) in the selected row.  I cant figure out how to pass the rowdata object back in the showModalDialog return value;

Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server side set ASPxGridView ClientInstanceName to some value (I will use "myGrid" in js code). 
Then your javascript code to fetch column values should look like this:

```js
myGrid.GetRowValues(myGrid.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'column1;column2;columnN', ProcessRowValues);

function ProcessRowValues(values) {
    alert('column1.value=' + values[0]);
    alert('column2.value=' + values[1]);
}
```

Notice that GetRowValues uses callback to fetch row values.